# Why doesn't the Logitech V200 mouse work with 64 bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech laptop mouse and Windows 7 64-bit.

I have installed the Logitech 64 bit drivers, and they're apparently communicating with the mouse - it shows my battery status, for example - but the mouse does not seem to work.

Is this a known issue, or is there a driver that works?

The mouse works fine on XP and Win7 32 bit without installing any drivers.

Comment: Does mouse shows properly in device manager? Try to uninstall and reinstall the driver.

Comment: It shows up, and is "working properly".

Comment: As I seen on google, it is a wireless mouse right?? If your device is "working properly" and everything looks being OK, I would tell you you should check if there isn't a "reset" or "connect" buttom above the mouse. Your problem should be related to the wireless connection between the mouse and it's host and not actually with drivers or anything else. It might be related to the wireless "sync".

Comment: What does Logitech support say?

Comment: It should work without drivers.  There isn't any reason it shouldn't work, if its not working, something else is going on.

Comment: @Diogo - I agree, but I have tried it on 2 different 64 bit Win7 systems and had the same problem.  Reset doesn't help - the Logitech 64 bit driver can talk to the mouse, and query the battery status, but not move the mouse.  And when it's plugged into a 32 bit Win7 system, or an XP system, it works fine, without installing drivers.